# Как очистить создаваемый список в JS

Tags: javascript

есть код:

```js
var leagues = document.getElementById("leagues");

var australia = ["Лига А", "НПЛ НСВ"];
var austria = ["Бундеслига", "Первая лига"];

var selectList = document.createElement("select");
selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
leagues.appendChild(selectList);


function jsCoun() {
  if (document.getElementById('country').value == "1") {
    for (var i = 0; i < australia.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.setAttribute("value", australia[i]);
      option.text = australia[i];
      selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
  } else if (document.getElementById('country').value == "2") {
    for (var i = 0; i < austria.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.setAttribute("value", austria[i]);
      option.text = austria[i];
      selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <p><select id="country" size="5" onchange="jsCoun()">
        <option disabled>Выберите страну</option>       
        <option value="1">Австралия</option>        
        <option value="2">Австрия</option>
       </select></p>
</form>
<span id="leagues"></span>
```

При выборе Австралии - создается список лиг в Австралии. При выборе Австрии соответственно лиг в Австрии. Но сейчас при создании списка лиг, массивы суммируются и если выбрать Австрию после Австралии, то к австралийским лигам прибавляются австрийские. Как очищать список, чтобы не суммировались массивы лиг?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не очищаете содержимое списка перед добавлением новых элементов. Вот этот JS код работает у меня:

```
var leagues = document.getElementById("leagues");

        var australia = ["Лига А","НПЛ НСВ"];
        var austria = ["Бундеслига", "Первая лига"];

        var selectList = document.createElement("select");
        selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
        leagues.appendChild(selectList);


        function jsCoun() {
            while(selectList.firstChild)// этот код удаляет содержимое списка 
                                        // перед добавлением новых элементов
                    {
                        selectList.removeChild(selectList.firstChild);
                    }
            if(document.getElementById('country').value == "1") {

                for (var i = 0; i < australia.length; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.setAttribute("value", australia[i]);
                    option.text = australia[i];

                    selectList.appendChild(option);
                }   
            } else if(document.getElementById('country').value == "2") {

                for (var i = 0; i < austria.length; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.setAttribute("value", austria[i]);
                    option.text = austria[i];


                    selectList.appendChild(option);


                }   
            }
        }
```

Comment: да, всё заработало. А то я мучился с selectList.removeChild, но не работало. А оказывается вот так надо) спасибо